# How to pass file name as a C++ compile argument to use in meson build?

Tags: gcc, built-in, compiler-flags, meson-build

I need to pass a compiler flag `-D__DEBUG_FILE__="src.cpp"` to g++ while compiling source file src.cpp. How can I achieve this in meson? I am aware of the `cpp_args` built-in option, but not able to figure out how to pass the file name in it.

I am aware that in make file you can write similar to below to achieve this: I am looking for a way to replicate this in meson build.

```
test.o : test.cpp     
g++ -D__MY_FILE__=\"$<\" -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: **Did you read the documentation** of [meson](https://mesonbuild.com/) and of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ?

Comment: Yes, I am aware that in make file you can write similar to below to achieve this: I am looking for a way to replicate this in meson build.

`test.o : test.cpp
    g++ -D__MY_FILE__=\"$<\" -c $< -o $@`

Comment: don't comment your question, but edit it

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I have arrived at the below:

```
trimprefix = run_command(['python', '-c', 'import sys, os; print(os.path.relpath(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]))', meson.current_source_dir(), meson.build_root()]).stdout().strip()

cpp_args : [ '-fmacro-prefix-map=@0@/='.format(trimprefix) ]
```

There are 2 problems still:

1. I still need to use `__FILE__`, I cannot define my own macro like `__MY_FILE__`
2. I need to compute `"trimprefix"` once for each sub directory

An in built option to use `@INPUT@`, `@BASENAME@` inside cpp_args could save a lot of this jugglery!
I have raised an issue in meson-build [#7485](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/7485) to address this - please up vote if you need this too.